# Suppose $A$ is nonempty, and that $c\in B, d\in B$ are distinct. Show that there is no surjection $F:A\to ^A\!\!{B}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ is nonempty, and that $c\in B, d\in B$ are distinct.  Using a diagonal argument, show that there is no surjection $F:A\to ^A\!\!{B}$.

**Attempt**: Assume there is such a surjection.  Then for every $F\in ^A\!\!{B}$, there is an $x\in A$ s.t. $F(x)=f$.  So $^AB=\{F(x):x\in A\}$.  Am I supposed to define a function $g:A\to B$ that switches the outputs of $c$ and $d$ or something of the sort?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem ans generalize.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully type theoretic proof of the following (constructive) theorem :

> If there is a surjection $A\to B^A$ then any map $f:B\to B$ has a fixed point.

Of course, classically this will imply that $B$ has at most one element, but this theorem is much more general than classical mathematics.

The proof works as follows : let $g: A\to B^A$ be your surjection and $f:B\to B$ any map.

Let $k : A\times A \to B$ be the decurryfication of $g$, and let $h: A\to A\times A\to B \to B$ be the composite of $f, k$ and the diagonal map.So $h:A\to B$, $h:B^A$

Now $g$ is surjective, so there is $s: A$ such that $g\circ s = h$. Now compute $g(s)(s) = h(s) = f(g(s)(s))$, so $g(s)(s)$ is a fixed point of $f$.

That construction can be done purely type theoretically so is valid in any cartesian closed category, and has as special cases Gödel's theorem, and Cantor's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

What's needed is Cantor's theorem "For every set $X$, $X\prec P(X)$", the theorem "For every set $X$, $P(X)\approx2^X$", and their proofs.

Here are two proofs of your statement:

1) Using Cantor's theorem: If there is a surjection $F:A\to B^A$, there would be a surjection $G:C\to 2^A$ for some $C\subseteq A$, contradiction. (How?)

2) Without: Let $F:A\to B^A$ be a function. We claim $F$ is not onto: Let $f:A\to B$ be defined by the map $a\to\begin{cases}
c\ \text{if }F(a)(a)\ne c\\
d\ \text{if }F(a)(a)=c.
\end{cases}$
Then $f\ne F(a)$ for all $a\in A$. (Why?) So $f\notin\operatorname{ran}(F)$ and $B^A\nsubseteq\operatorname{ran}(F)$.